# Angular 2 cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: http, angular

I have seen this error on SO quite a few times, all I can find on it is that I need to make sure that I have my service Provided in my app.modules, and then call it in my constructor of my component. I have done this and am still getting the error. Also I have both http and HTTPMODULES in my application. The error only occurs when I use the **delete** functionality in my application. Here is the error `error_handler.js:45 EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`, here is some relevant code....

**app.module.ts**

```
  import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

    import { HttpModule, JsonpModule }     from '@angular/http'; <------------HTTP

    import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
    import { PostRantComponent } from './postRant.component';
    import { PostDataService } from './PostData.Service';    <------------service
    import { Constants } from './app.const.service';



    import { Routing } from './app.routes';
    import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';


    @NgModule({
        imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), BrowserModule, Routing, FormsModule,   HttpModule, JsonpModule],
        declarations: [AppComponent,,PostRantComponent],
        providers: [PostDataService, Constants],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
     })
     export class AppModule { }
```

**Service** (tried cutting it down to just show relevant code)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { PostViewModel } from './models/Post';
import { Constants } from './app.const.service';

@Injectable()
 export class PostDataService{

private actionUrl: string;
private headers: Headers;
constructor( private _http: Http, private _constants: Constants ){

    this.actionUrl = _constants.ServerWithApi;

    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.headers.append('Accept','application/json');
}

public GetAll = (): Observable<PostViewModel[]> => {
    return this._http.get(this.actionUrl)
    .map((response: Response) => <PostViewModel[]>response.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

public Delete = (id: string) =>{
   return this._http.delete(this.actionUrl + id)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
}    

}
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, Attribute, OnInit,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { PostViewModel } from './models/Post';
import { PostDataService } from './PostData.Service';
import { Constants } from './app.const.service';

@Component({
   selector: 'postRant',
   templateUrl: 'html/postRant.html',
})
export class PostRantComponent implements OnInit {
   txtTitle: string;
    txtDescription: string;

    public myPosts : Array<PostViewModel>;
    public newPost : PostViewModel = new PostViewModel();
    constructor(private auth:Auth, private _dataservice: PostDataService){ 

  }

ngOnInit(){
  this.getAllItems();
}

private getAllItems():void {
  this._dataservice
    .GetAll()
    .subscribe((Post: Array<PostViewModel>) => this.myPosts = Post,
      error => console.log(error),
        () => console.log('get all items complete'))
}

delete(id){
  console.log(id);
   this._dataservice.Delete(id)
    .subscribe((res) => {
      this.myPosts = res;
    });
      var index = this.myPosts.findIndex(x => x.id == id);
      this.myPosts.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

If you are interested in all the code I have it posted on my git located [here](https://github.com/bcrawford11/Angular2-w-CRUD-Api-MongoDb/tree/master/UI/src/app/components), however it is rather large.

**EDIT**
picture of error....[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears that the error is produced by line 52 of `PostData.Service.ts`
i.e. `var applicationError = error.headers.get('Application-Error');`

this makes me guess that your GetAll Http call is erroring out, but the server you are asking for data is not returning data in the format of `error.headers`

Add a `debugger;` to the handleError and check the object that it is receiving.

Comment: You are correct the problem was not on the front end of my application, it is on the backend in my api. Thank you!